# How can I easier update my application to server using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

OK, here is the problem, I have a running application on the server, and a developing version. User have more and more request and suggestion about the site. So, we need to upgrade the site and the database. Since the database update, we need some database schema change. How can we handle this? Because if the php program, we can easy as upload all the script files and deploy, but the database, it there any 'diff' for the database? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually log every change I make to the database structure while I develop. Later I just apply the same changes to production.

Comment: any recommend tools for logging?

Comment: It depends on the database you are using. I haven't found anything for MySQL, but for example Firebird's admin. tool FlameRobin has an option to log each change to a separate sql file named 1.sql, 2.sql, 3.sql etc. That way it's easy to roll database forward from any version.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [migrations](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-migrations), kinda like rails